# ImportError with Python OpenCV (undefined symbol)

Tags: python, opencv

I built OpenCV 3.1.0 from source, and when I try to `import cv2` in Python I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv9Algorithm7getListERSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS7_EE
```

OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I followed [this guide to build OpenCV with CUDA 8.0](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d6/d15/tutorial_building_tegra_cuda.html).

Answer (score 1):

Install glib!

for example, if you use Anaconda, run this command:

> `conda install -c anaconda glib`

Comment: Would you kindly elaborate on the relevancy to this question?